# Deleting from a XML using multiple criteria

Tags: xml, replace, notepad++

I'm looking for a way to basically do a Search/Replace on a XML document to delete lines that contain certain values. Think a DELETE SQL query with an IN operator - sadly I'm not in a position where I can convert this filesystem into a database.

For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<colu id="1">   
    <product id="995462066"/>
    <product id="995462067"/>
    <product id="995462068"/>
    <product id="995462069"/>
</colu> 

<colu id="2">   
    <product id="995462050"/>
    <product id="995462091"/>
    <product id="995462096"/>
    <product id="995462099"/>
</colu>
```

In the above I would like to find and replace any lines containing 995462099, 995462091, and 995462066.

On this scale I could simply do three Find/Replaces but the file I'm working on is over 30,000 entries long and I have 600 different search terms that need to be removed. I already have a list of entries to remove (which are formatted with the [product id="#"/]) I just need a method to run that list through.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in Notepad++, unless you write your own plugin.

I think the easiest solution would be to pick your favourite scripting/programming language and do it yourself.

Otherwise you could go the command line way and use tools like sed and awk (you can find lots of information about these by searching stackoverflow or google).